# Replace dashes in Timestamp

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with timestamps like so

```
   2014-06-04 00:00:06.487,,4324
   2014-06-04 00:00:43.487,,-2321
```

I'd like to replace the timestamps - (dashes) with a / (forward slash)

so instead like so:

```
   2014/06/04 00:00:06.487,,4324
   2014/06/04 00:00:43.487,,-2321
```

I am wondering if its possible to do this with sed or not and how would I do this?

Comment: A small note for future Netizens. If you care for being universally understood, you should use the standard formats defined in ISO8601 for timestamps and dates. For dates, it uses dashes as in YYYY-MM-DD - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 4):

I would do :

```
awk 'gsub(/-/,"/",$1)||7' file
```

this will only replace the `-` in first column, which in your example is the date, and leave other `-` untouched.

example:

```
kent$  cat f
2014-06-04 00:00:06.487,,4324
2014-06-04 00:00:43.487,,-2321

kent$  awk 'gsub(/-/,"/",$1)||7' f
2014/06/04 00:00:06.487,,4324
2014/06/04 00:00:43.487,,-2321
```

if your date string could be other columns too, we have to go thru all fields, and check if it matches `xxxx-xx-xx` then do the replacement. it is also an easy task for awk. let me know if it is in this case.

Comment: The `awk` does remove the spaces in front of the date, `sed` does not.  Not sure of that is a problem for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Through GNU sed,

```
$ sed -r 's~-([0-9]{2}\b)~/\1~g' file
   2014/06/04 00:00:06.487,,4324
   2014/06/04 00:00:43.487,,-2321
```

Through perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's~-(?=\d{2}\b)~/~g' file
   2014/06/04 00:00:06.487,,4324
   2014/06/04 00:00:43.487,,-2321
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a numeric argument to sed to make it match only 1 pattern, twice. (Could not manage to do it in one single command).

```
$ echo '2014-06-04 00:00:43.487,,-2321' | sed -e 's@-@/@1;s@-@/@1'
2014/06/04 00:00:43.487,,-2321
```

You can also do it easily in Perl using the same logic:

```
$ echo '2014-06-04 00:00:43.487,,-2321' |perl -ne 'print join("/", split(/-/, $_, 3));'
2014/06/04 00:00:43.487,,-2321
```